# How do I get the position of the item shown in my recyclerview from outside of the adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a fixed number of items. I've implemented a `SnapHelper` to ensure that only one `CardView` item is visible at a time. How can I get the `CardView` position from outside of the adapter class? The position will need to be returned `onCreate` and `onSwipe` to the next `CardView` item. I tried to use a `setTag()` in my `onBindViewHolder` class and a `getTag()` in my activity, but that didn't seem to work.

Current code:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerOne = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerHomeFavouriteTable.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerOne);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerHomeFavouriteTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the recycler view item position. there are two method

`getLayoutPostion()`

> Returns the position of the ViewHolder in terms of the latest layout pass.
>   This position is mostly used by RecyclerView components to be consistent while
>   RecyclerView lazily processes adapter updates.

`getAdapterPosition()`

> Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder

they are both belong to `ViewHolder`, so I think, you can set a tag to item holder. then get the `ViewHolder` according to tag, then use `ViewHodler` to get the position.